# how to do a sip call from sipp

Tags: linux, voip, sip

I am newest user using SIPp ,
I am trying to made a sip call from SIPp program on Linux but i fail on it .
i want a command to call phone number (14042835351) from sip domain (80.81.82.83) with same username and password (2004) .

this is a Tutorials for SIPp program

http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html
http://wiki.sipfoundry.org/display/sipXecs/Using+SIPp+to+run+performance+tests

Output of sipp -sn uas :

```
sipp -sn uas
Warning: open file limit > FD_SETSIZE; limiting max. # of open files to FD_SETSIZE = 1024
------------------------------ Scenario Screen -------- [1-9]: Change Screen --
  Port   Total-time  Total-calls  Transport
  5060      67.42 s            0  UDP

  0 new calls during 0.306 s period      1 ms scheduler resolution
  0 calls                                Peak was 0 calls, after 0 s
  0 Running, 2 Paused, 0 Woken up
  0 dead call msg (discarded)          
  3 open sockets                        

                                 Messages  Retrans   Timeout   Unexpected-Msg
  ----------> INVITE             0         0         0         0        

  <---------- 180                0         0                            
  <---------- 200                0         0         0                  
  ----------> ACK         E-RTD1 0         0         0         0        

  ----------> BYE                0         0         0         0        
  <---------- 200                0         0                            
  [   4000ms] Pause              0                             0        
------------------------------ Test Terminated --------------------------------


----------------------------- Statistics Screen ------- [1-9]: Change Screen --
  Start Time             | 2014-10-27   22:47:16:670    1414442836.670779            
  Last Reset Time        | 2014-10-27   22:48:23:792    1414442903.792575            
  Current Time           | 2014-10-27   22:48:24:120    1414442904.120735            
-------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------
  Counter Name           | Periodic value            | Cumulative value
-------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------
  Elapsed Time           | 00:00:00:328              | 00:01:07:449             
  Call Rate              |    0.000 cps              |    0.000 cps             
-------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------
  Incoming call created  |        0                  |        0                 
  OutGoing call created  |        0                  |        0                 
  Total Call created     |                           |        0                 
  Current Call           |        0                  |                          
-------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------
  Successful call        |        0                  |        0                 
  Failed call            |        0                  |        0                 
-------------------------+---------------------------+--------------------------
  Response Time 1        | 00:00:00:000              | 00:00:00:000             
  Call Length            | 00:00:00:000              | 00:00:00:000             
------------------------------ Test Terminated --------------------------------
```

Best Regards